# MATLAB Speed Optimisation

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

Can anyone help? I am a fairly experienced Matlab user but am having trouble speeding up the code below.

The fastest time I have been able to achieve for one run through all three loops, using 12 cores, is ~200s. The actual function will be called ~720 times and at this rate will take over 40hrs to execute. According to the Matlab profiler, the majority of cpu time is spent in the exponential function call. I've managed to speed this up quite substantially using a gpuArray and then running the exp call on a Quadro 4000 graphics card however this then prevents the parfor loop from being used, since the workstation has only one graphics card, which obliterates any gains. Can anyone help, or is this code close to the optimum that can be achieved  using Matlab? I have written a very crude c++ implementation with openMP but achieved little gain.

Many thanks in advance

```
function SPEEDtest_CPU

% Variable setup:
% - For testing I'll use random variables. These will actually be fed into 
%   the function for the real version of this code.
sy    = 320;
sx    = 100;
sz    = 32;
A     = complex(rand(sy,sx,sz),rand(sy,sx,sz));
B     = complex(rand(sy,sx,sz),rand(sy,sx,sz));
C     = rand(sy,sx);
D     = rand(sy*sx,1);
F     = zeros(sy,sx,sz);
x     = rand(sy*sx,1);  
y     = rand(sy*sx,1);
x_ind = (1:sx) - (sx / 2) - 1;
y_ind = (1:sy) - (sy / 2) - 1;


% MAIN LOOPS 
%  - In the real code this set of three loops will be called ~720 times!
%  - Using 12 cores, the fastest I have managed is ~200 seconds for one
%    call of this function.
tic
for z = 1 : sz
    A_slice = A(:,:,z);
    A_slice = A_slice(:);
    parfor cx = 1 : sx       
        for cy = 1 : sy       
            E = ( x .* x_ind(cx) ) + ( y .* y_ind(cy) ) + ( C(cy,cx) .* D );                                                          

            F(cy,cx,z) = (B(cy,cx,z) .* exp(-1i .* E))' * A_slice; 
        end       
    end   
end
toc

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Some things to think about:

Have you considered using singles?

Can you vectorize the cx, cy portion so that they represent array operations?

Consider changing the floating point rounding or signalling modes.

Comment: Single can give you a memory reduction. However, based on this I think it will prevent optimization:http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~marios/matlab/accel_matlab.pdf , of course a test won't hurt.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin you are wrong. Matlab is able to effectively translate single precision instructions into their SSE form. I have witnessed this effect on numerous occasions. You can tell when this is happening because your C++ performance is the same as your Matlab. I can't find a reference to numerical precision in that document?

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, converting to single precision sped the calculation up by ~10%. I find this surprising, since I've tried this before and not seen such a gain. Maybe this is related to passing less data to multiple cores?

Comment: @Mikhail I based my comment on the comment at the bottom right of page 2 from the pdf. Perhaps I misinterpreted this or is it not applicable/relevant here. I do remember some occasions where executing single calculations was slower than doubles.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Oh I see. Anyways I speak from experience, and this paper is from 2002.

Comment: @jack You should see a much larger increase, perhaps 30%. check that everything evaluates to single precision. Stray `0.5*myarray` will mess it up. Complex exponentials are mathematically intensive and  can easily take longer then memory access. Also having your memory footprint should help with the bandwidth. Lastly, many GPUs have a 20x discrepancy in performance between double and single.

Answer (score 2):

If your data are real (not complex), as in your example, you can save time replacing

```
(B(cy,cx,z) .* exp(-1i .* E))'
```

by

```
(B(cy,cx,z) .* (cos(E)+1i*sin(E))).'
```

Specifically, on my machine `(cos(x)+1i*sin(x)).'` takes **19%** less time than `exp(-1i .* x)'`.

---

If `A` and `B` are complex: `E` is still real, so you can precompute `Bconj = conj(B)` outside the loops (this takes about 10 ms with your data size, and it's done only once) and then replace

```
(B(cy,cx,z) .* exp(-1i .* E))'
```

by

```
(Bconj(cy,cx,z) .* (cos(E)+1i*sin(E))).'
```

to obtain a similar gain.

Comment: Thanks, though an interesting result, in this case A and B are complex. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @jack See updated answer (second part, after horizontal line)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways of speeding up MATLAB code; *preallocation* and *vectorisation*.

You have preallocated well but there is no vectorisation. In order to best learn how to do this you need to have a good grasp of linear algebra and the use of `repmat` to expand vectors into multiple dimensions.

Vectorisation can result in multiple orders of magnitude speedup and will use the cores optimally (provided the flag is up).

What is the mathematical expression you are calculating and I may be able to lend a hand?

Comment: Thanks luke. I've already tried vectorising the code in this way, to remove the inner loop, but did not see a speed up. Most probably due to the resulting large matrix sizes that have to be manipulated. But then maybe it was just a bad implementation on my behalf. The function is actually an inverse encoding function for the reconstruction of magnetic resonance images, and is fairly similar to a discrete Fourier transform with an added phase term ( C(cy,cx) .* D).

Comment: Hmmm... that is strange behaviour. I'm stumped I'm afraid. Best of luck finding a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can move `x .* x_ind(cx)` out of the innermost loop. I don't have a GPU handy to test the timings, but you could split the code into three sections to allow you to use the GPU and parfor

```
for z = 1 : sz
    E = zeros(sy*sx,sx,sy);
    A_slice = A(:,:,z);
    A_slice = A_slice(:);
    parfor cx = 1 : sx
        temp = ( x .* x_ind(cx) );       
        for cy = 1 : sy       
            E(:, cx, cy) = temp + ( y .* y_ind(cy) ) + ( C(cy,cx) .* D );                                                          
        end
    end
    temp = zeros(zeros(sy*sx,sx,sy));
    for cx = 1 : sx
        for cy = 1 : sy       
             % Ideally use your GPU magic here
             temp(:, cx, cy) = exp(-1i .* E(:, cx, cy)));
        end
    end
    parfor cx = 1 : sx
        for cy = 1 : sy       
            F(cy,cx,z) = (B(cy,cx,z) .* temp(:, cx, cy)' * A_slice; 
        end       
    end   
end
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but unfortunately using this method makes E around 4GB in single precision and too large for the memory of the GPU. Reducing the size of E, by creating a temporary variable for every cx in the cx loop, gets around this memory issue. However, then too much time is spent passing information back and forth between the GPU and CPU and the whole thing slows down again.

Comment: @jack so how do you get your GPU speed up?

Answer (score 0):

To allow for proper paralellization you need to make sure the loops are completely independant, hence check whether not assigning to `E` in each run helps.

Furthermore try to vectorize as much as possible, one simple example could be: `y.*y_ind(cy)`

If you just create the proper index for all values at once, you can take this out of the lowest loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps much with speed - but as E is basically a sum maybe you can use that `exp (i cx(A+1)x) = exp(i cx(A) x) * exp(i x)` and `exp(i x)` can be calculated beforehand.

That way you wouldn't have to evaluate exp each iteration - but just have to multiplicate, which should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other good advise given here by others, the multiplication by `A_slice` is independent of the `cx,cy` loops and can be taken outside them, multiplying `F` once both loops have finished.

Similarly, the conjugation of `B*exp(...)` can also be done en-bulk outside the `cx,cy` loop, before multiplication by `A_slice`.

Answer (score 0):

This line: ( x .* x_ind(cx) ) + ( y .* y_ind(cy) ) + ( C(cy,cx) .* D );

is some type of convolution, is it not? Circular convolution is much faster in the frequency domain, and the conversion to/from frequency domain is optimized using the FTT.